# how to solve Request Entity Too Large issue in elastic search?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

We are trying to index using BulkRequest java RestHighclient 6.2.3. Elastic search is hosted on aws.

We are getting following issue while indexing:

```
URI [/_bulk?timeout=120s], status line [HTTP/1.1 413 Request Entity Too Large]
    {"Message":"Request size exceeded 104857600 bytes"}
```

How to resolve this in java RestHighClient jar?

Comment: did you get any work around for this ?

Answer (score 2):

Based on [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-http.html#_http_settings), the maximum size of an HTTP request body is 100mb (you can change it using the `http.max_content_length` setting).

Keep in mind that the Elasticseach instance hosted on AWS also has a limitation on the HTTP request payload. You can see the details [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-limits.html).